# Correctly setting a focus point for image scalling

Tags: android, scaling, surfaceview, multi-touch

I have a `SurfaceView` that is resposible for drawing a `Bitmap` as a background and another one that will be used as an overlay. So I've decided to do all transformations using a `Matrix` that can be used for both bitmaps as it is (I think) one of the fastest ways to do it without using OpenGL.

I've been able to implement panning around and zooming but I have some problems with what I've came with:

- I wasn't able to find a way how to focus on the center of the two
  fingers while zooming, the image always resets to its initial state
  (that is, without panning nor scalling) before the new scale being
  applied. Besides looking wrong, that doesn't allow the user to zoom
  out to see the whole image and then zoom in on the part that is
  important.
- After the scalling operation the image won't be at the
  same place after the new draw pass because the translation value will
  be different.

Is there a way to achieve that using a Matrix or is there another solution?

Code is below (I use a `SurfaceHolder` in a separate thread do lock the SurfaceView canvas and call its `doDraw` method):

```
public class MapSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mTransformationMatrix, mPaintAA);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    mOriginalDistance = MathUtils.distanceBetween(event.getX(0), event.getX(1), event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                    mScreenMidpoint = MathUtils.midpoint(event.getX(0), event.getX(1), event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                    mImageMidpoint = MathUtils.midpoint((mXPosition+event.getX(0))/mScale, (mXPosition+event.getX(1))/mScale, (mYPosition+event.getY(0))/mScale, (mYPosition+event.getY(1))/mScale);
                    mOriginalScale = mScale;
                }
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                mOriginalTouchPoint = new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                mOriginalPosition = new Point(mXPosition, mYPosition);
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    final double currentDistance = MathUtils.distanceBetween(event.getX(0), event.getX(1), event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                    if (mIsZooming || currentDistance - mOriginalDistance > mPinchToZoomTolerance || mOriginalDistance - currentDistance > mPinchToZoomTolerance) {
                        final float distanceRatio = (float) (currentDistance / mOriginalDistance);
                        float tempZoom = mOriginalScale * distanceRatio;

                        mScale = Math.min(10, Math.max(Math.min((float)getHeight()/(float)mBitmap.getHeight(), (float)getWidth()/(float)mBitmap.getWidth()), tempZoom));
                        mScale = (float) MathUtils.roundToDecimals(mScale, 1);
                        mIsZooming = true;
                        mTransformationMatrix = new Matrix();
                        mTransformationMatrix.setScale(mScale, mScale);//, mImageMidpoint.x, mImageMidpoint.y);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Dragging");
                        mIsZooming = false;
                        final int deltaX = (int) ((int) (mOriginalTouchPoint.x - event.getX()));
                        final int deltaY = (int) ((int) (mOriginalTouchPoint.y - event.getY()));
                        mXPosition = mOriginalPosition.x + deltaX;  
                        mYPosition = mOriginalPosition.y + deltaY;
                        validatePositions();
                        mTransformationMatrix = new Matrix();
                        mTransformationMatrix.setScale(mScale, mScale);
                        mTransformationMatrix.postTranslate(-mXPosition, -mYPosition);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                mIsZooming = false;
                validatePositions();
                mTransformationMatrix = new Matrix();
                mTransformationMatrix.setScale(mScale, mScale);
                mTransformationMatrix.postTranslate(-mXPosition, -mYPosition);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void validatePositions() {
        // Lower right corner
        mXPosition = Math.min(mXPosition, (int)((mBitmap.getWidth() * mScale)-getWidth()));
        mYPosition = Math.min(mYPosition, (int)((mBitmap.getHeight() * mScale)-getHeight()));
        // Upper left corner
        mXPosition = Math.max(mXPosition, 0);
        mYPosition = Math.max(mYPosition, 0);
        // Image smaller than the container, should center it
        if (mBitmap.getWidth() * mScale <= getWidth()) {
            mXPosition = (int) -((getWidth() - (mBitmap.getWidth() * mScale))/2);
        }
        if (mBitmap.getHeight() * mScale <= getHeight()) { 
            mYPosition = (int) -((getHeight() - (mBitmap.getHeight() * mScale))/2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of resetting the transformation matrix every time using new Matrix(), try updating it using post*(). This way, you do only operations relative to the screen. It is easier to think in terms: "zoom to this point on the screen".

Now some code. Having calculated mScale in zooming part:

```
...
mScale = (float) MathUtils.roundToDecimals(mScale, 1);
float ratio = mScale / mOriginalScale;
mTransformationMatrix.postScale(ratio, ratio, mScreenMidpoint.x, mScreenMidpoint.y);
```

It might be even better to recalculate mScreenMidpoint on each zooming touch event. This would allow user to change the focus point a bit while zooming. For me, it is more natural than having the focus point frozen after first two finger touch.

During dragging, you translate using deltaX and deltaY instead of absolute points:

```
mTransformationMatrix.postTranslate(-deltaX, -deltaY);
```

Of course now you have to change your validatePositions() method to:

- ensure deltaX and deltaY do not make image move too much, or
- use transformation matrix to check if image is off screen and then move it to counter that

I will describe the second method, as it is more flexible and allows to validate zooming as well.

We calculate how much image is off screen and then move it using those values:

```
void validate() {

    mTransformationMatrix.mapRect(new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight()));

    float height = rect.height();
    float width = rect.width();

    float deltaX = 0, deltaY = 0;

    // Vertical delta
    if (height < mScreenHeight) {
        deltaY = (mScreenHeight - height) / 2 - rect.top;
    } else if (rect.top > 0) {
        deltaY = -rect.top;
    } else if (rect.bottom < mScreenHeight) {
        deltaY = mScreenHeight - rect.bottom;
    }

    // Horziontal delta
    if (width < mScreenWidth) {
        deltaX = (mScreenWidth - width) / 2 - rect.left;
    } else if (rect.left > 0) {
        deltaX = -rect.left;
    } else if (rect.right < mScreenWidth) {
        deltaX = mScreenWidth - rect.right;
    }

    mTransformationMatrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working with the same Matrix and using screen coordinates really helped me!